# Файл с временем посещения (online/offline)

Tags: python

Есть рабочий код, который создает файл и записывает online или offline пользователь. Проблема в том, что каждый раз когда запускается скрипт, он перезаписывает данные и информация о времени неверная, так как скрипт перезаписывает значение когда пользователь был online или offline. Как можно сделать так, чтобы код видел что уже есть запись о том что пользователь online и не надо еще раз перезаписывать время. Код конечно не мечта, но как смог сделал,

```
import datetime
import subprocess

with open('File.txt', 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.run('arp -a', stdout=file, check=True)




ResultCreate = open('Result.txt', 'w')
ResultCreate.write("Employee name:             Online from:                  Offline from:")
ResultCreate.close()




findBA = open('File.txt', 'r')
wordBA = '01-00-5e-00-00-16'
ResultBA = open('Result.txt', 'a')
dataBA = datetime.datetime.now()

if wordBA in findBA.read():
    ResultBA.write("\n#Barchunov Alexey          ")
    ResultBA.write(str(dataBA))
    ResultBA.write("    - ")
    ResultBA.close()
else:
    ResultBA.write("\n Barchunov Alexey          ")
    ResultBA.write("-                             ")
    ResultBA.write(str(dataBA))
    ResultBA.close()




findRY = open('File.txt', 'r')
wordRY = '00-0e-c6-e3-4e-3e'
ResultRY = open('Result.txt', 'a')
dataRY = datetime.datetime.now()

if wordRY in findRY.read():
    ResultRY.write("\n#Rakishev Yerassyl         ")
    ResultRY.write(str(dataRY))
    ResultRY.write("    -")
    ResultRY.close()
else:
    ResultRY.write("\n Rakishev Yerassyl         ")
    ResultRY.write("-                             ")
    ResultRY.write(str(dataRY))
    ResultRY.close()




findKZ = open('File.txt', 'r')
wordKZ = '00-1b-78-0d-2a-ab'
ResultKZ = open('Result.txt', 'a')
dataKZ = datetime.datetime.now()

if wordKZ in findKZ.read():
    ResultKZ.write("\n#Kunaev Zhalgas            ")
    ResultKZ.write(str(dataKZ))
    ResultKZ.write("    -")
    ResultKZ.close()
else:
    ResultKZ.write("\n Kunaev Zhalgas            ")
    ResultKZ.write("-                             ")
    ResultKZ.write(str(dataKZ))
    ResultKZ.close()
```

Comment: Если нужно дозаписывать данные в файл, то нужно открывать в режиме `'a'`, а не `'w'`. Если нужно записывать только если данных еще нет, то пробовать читать файл, если файла нет или файл пустой (вылетело исключение при попытке открытия или чтения), то открывать в режиме записи и перезаписывать.

Comment: это понятно, я про то что если уже есть значение когда пользователь онлайн, чтобы скрипт при запуске не перезаписывал время, потому что при каждом запуске он перезаписывает время входа

Comment: Открытие в режиме 'w' перезаписывает файл. Если не нужно чтобы перезаписывало файл, не открывайте его в этом режиме (открывайте в другом режиме, например - в каком именно это зависит от задачи, по вашему описанию не очень понятно что именно нужно).

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при запуске скрипта, он записывал онлайн или оффлайн пользователь и во сколько в последний раз был онлайн или оффлайн. Код выше впринципе делает это, но проблема в том что код должен через какое-то определенное время выполнять команду arp-a чтобы знать актуальную информацию кто онлайн или оффлайн. И при запуске скрипта, он перезаписывает предыдущее значение входа. Т.Е. Скрипт запустился впервый раз и записал что пользователь онлайн с 10-00, через пять минут скрипт еще раз запускается и перезаписывает время на 10-05 и так каждый раз при запуске.

Comment: Ну значит при каждом запуске открывать файл на чтение, а не на запись, смотреть его содержимое. См. первый комментарий.

Comment: Вообще, в вашем случае вместо кучки файлов я бы использовал базу данных, например sqlite.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже думаю на счет базы данных, просто пока даже логически не могу додумать как сделать так чтобы код понимал что не нужно каждый раз перезаписывать время, а чтобы всегда показывал первое значение до тех пор пока статус не изменится на оффлайн

Comment: "как сделать так чтобы код понимал что не нужно каждый раз перезаписывать время" - да я уже несколько раз написал, просто при запуске нужно читать файл вместо того чтобы сразу перезаписывать.

Comment: Если содержимое не важно, а просто нужно проверить наличие файла, то вызывать функцию [exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) из os.path

Comment: Я это понимаю. Вы меня недопоняли, если запустите код, то думаю поймете о чем я. Если перезаписывать файл с атрибутом 'a' , то просто создается новая строка, а мне нужно чтобы код при запуске отрабатывал apr-a но при этом не перезаписывал значение времени во втором файле, в общем возможно есть какое-то решение, но я пока не додумал как это сделать

Comment: Я как раз понимаю, и понимаю как сделать) Не нужно в  режиме 'a', нужно в режиме 'r' (если просто проверить наличие файла - то вызывать функцию exists из os.path), и в зависимости от результата (успешности или неуспешности) потом уже открывать в режиме 'w'.

Comment: В общем создается файл с фамилией и временем во сколько пользователь онлайн или оффлайн: Иванов     онлайн с 12-00. А если снова запустить скрипт через 5 минут, то файл будет иметь такую запись: Иванов   онлайн с 12-05, т.е. предыдущее значение перезаписалось, а если использовать 'a', то создастся новая строка, а replace не могу использовать так как нужно какое-то точное значение чтобы заменить его, а время может меняться

Comment: Да забудьте про 'a', читайте через 'r' (не совсем забудьте, а в данном случае))

Comment: Спасибо, попробую) Я так понял тогда лучше 'import subprocess
with open('File.txt', 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.run('arp -a', stdout=file, check=True)'   вывести в отдельный скрипт, так как мне нужно чтобы он запускался каждые 2-3 минуты.